# Background Application: NSAlert before shutdown

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa, shutdown

I want to have a **status bar** application that will display a `NSAlert` before the system shutdown/reboot. (Just a `NSStatusItem`, no window.)

It detected the shutdown and show the alert, but before the user could interact with the alert, the application terminated then system turned off.

Is there a way to force the system to wait for the alert to finish before the system shutdown?

**EDIT:** The code did work if the application was shown in the Dock, but will not work if it's a `NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Accessory` or an `UI Element`. I tried to restored it back to the Dock before it quits but before it can pop up again it's been terminated.

Here's the code example:

```
func receivedPowerOffNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

        let myAlert: NSAlert = NSAlert()
        myAlert.alertStyle = NSAlertStyle.CriticalAlertStyle
        myAlert.messageText = "Title"
        myAlert.informativeText = "Please wait for this alert"
        myAlert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        myAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Not OK")
        let response = myAlert.runModal()
        if response != NSModalResponseOK {
            // Do something here before shutdown the system.
        }
    }
    NSApplication.sharedApplication().replyToApplicationShouldTerminate(true)
}

func applicationShouldTerminate(sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplicationTerminateReply {
    // userQuit = if the termination was caused by the Quit menu.
    return userQuit ? NSApplicationTerminateReply.TerminateNow : NSApplicationTerminateReply.TerminateLater
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after back and forth emails with Apple's **Developer Technical Support** (**DTS**), **the short answer is it's impossible** (for a **LSUIElement**/**Agent** to trap a *shutdown/reboot* process):

Quote from an Apple Employee:

> The rules change in AppKit for apps that are user-agent based.  They
>   are designed not to interact with the user, even through our
>   documentation states you can add windows.  Since your app has an
>   NSStatusItem, which constitutes a UI, it should not be user-agent
>   based.  You are interacting with the user in this case.

I did ask if there's any "*internal*" ways. The answer was still no.